# Find a way to determine inside function if method is called on the return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My class looks like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = []

    ...

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return bar
```

Is there a way to find out inside `foo` whether a method will be called on its return value? I would like to be able to change the return value of `foo` depending on whether

```
a.foo.foobar()
```

or

```
a.foo
```

is called.

Comment: Could you provide some broader information - what are you trying to achieve, why do you need to implement this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It sounds like you are going after a wrong method of solution.

Comment: The intent was to return a list of objects if `a.foo` is used directly, and to return another object if `a.foo.foobar()` is used that can be used to do certain operations using the list. However, I've resorted to returning a list-like custom class that does everything I want, I am just curious if this pattern is possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a proxy class wrapping `self.bar` (or just `self` FWIW) in `foo()`) and overload the proxy's `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__` methods (more tricky and can slow down your program quite a bit but well...).

Now the question is: what is your real problem ? There might be better / safer solutions...

Answer (score 2):

for the fun of it...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import traceback

def how_was_i_called():
    call=traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)[0][3]
    print "I was called like this: %s"%call

how_was_i_called()
try:
    how_was_i_called().foobar()
except AttributeError:
  pass
```

returns:

```
I was called like this: how_was_i_called()
I was called like this: how_was_i_called().foobar()
```

but please do not use hacks like this in real applications...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. `foo` returns, and what happens with the return value after that is an entirely separate issue.

You could do this, for example:

```
 result = a.foo
 if some_condition:
      result.foobar()
```

e.g. accessing the `foobar` method on `a.foo` is an entirely separate expression that may or may not be executed. This could happen at a *much* later time too, or in a separate thread, or after serialising the object to disk, then loading it again, etc.

You can hook into attribute access *on the returned object*, but that'll be too late for your `foo` property to alter behaviour.